# Progress Bar на сайт с меняющимся текстом

Tags: javascript, html, css

Уважаемые разработчики, прошу помощи, не как не могу найти прогресс бар с меняющимся текстом, то есть, например когда у прогресс бара по мере его загрузки процент от 0-20 высвечивается текст №1, когда от 20% до 45% допустим высвечивается текст №2, когда от 45-80% текст №3, от 80-100% текст №4, но это к примеру, но суть вы поняли по мере загрузки прогресс бара текст меняется, весь интернет переискал только вижу просто прогресс бары без текста, но только одно решение нашел с неполным кодом, от этом писал здесь https://qna.habr.com/q/1071162, может у кого то есть готовый функционал такого бара?

Comment: не пойму, в чем сложность в момент обновления прогресса загрузки, проверить процент отображаемый пользователю и на основе этих данных вывести необходимый текст?

Comment: @Хацкер Но пока загрузка идет, на 20%-40% выводился что бы определенный текст, на 40%-60% определенный текст и тд

Comment: Прогресс вам уже реализовали, а как обработать массив, думайте уже сами. Искать готовый код - это не выход, вы либо программист, либо заказчик. Программист пишет код, я понимаю, что логика самого прогресса - круглая, не совсем простая, но отобразить элементы меняя условия, если вы этого не можете, опираясь даже на подсказки, тогда мой совет начать изучать циклы и массивы, а не писать что-то сложное.

Comment: WalkMess увидел спасибо)))